# Conditional probability - a system with 3 parts

Tags: probability

I fail to see what I have done wrong solving the following problem:
Consider a system with 3 parts A,B,C. Part A works with probability 0.8, part B with 0.8 and part C with 0.9 (they are independent). The system is considered to work only if there are at least two parts working. I wish to calculate what the probability of part A working, considering the system doesn't work. What I did is: $$P\left(\text{part A working}\mid\text{system isn't working}\right)=P\left(\text{system isn't working}\mid\text{part A working}\right)\frac{P\left(\text{part A working}\right)}{P\left(\text{system isn't working}\right)}=\frac{0.8\cdot0.2\cdot0.1\cdot0.8}{1-\left[\left(0.8\cdot0.8\cdot0.1\right)+\left(0.8\cdot0.8\cdot0.9\right)+\left(0.2\cdot0.8\cdot0.9\right)+\left(0.8\cdot0.2\cdot0.9\right)\right]}$$ $$\approx0.177$$

But I seem to get the wrong answer. I went over it again and again and I fail to find my mistake (I used Bayes formula).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in the numerator, in finding probability that the system does not work but part $1$ works (I am calling it part $1$ instead of part $A$).

If $B$ is the event of system not working,

$P(B) = 1 - [0.2 \times 0.8 \times 0.9 + 0.8 \times 0.2 \times 0.9 + 0.8 \times 0.8 \times 0.1 + 0.8 \times 0.8 \times 0.9] = 0.072$

If $A$ is the event of part $1$ working,

$P(A \cap B) = 0.8 \times 0.2 \times 0.1 = 0.016$

So $P(A \ |B) = \displaystyle \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{2}{9}$

Comment: Thank you! I indeed accidently multiplied also by $0.8$ in the numerator and we receive the same answer now.

Comment: @Darkenin yes that seemed to be the only mistake. One suggestion - when you are typing in decimal numbers, please use $\times$ instead of $\cdot$ for multiplication sign.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it right except when it comes to the numerical expression. You shouldn't multiply by $0.8$ twice but only once.

$P(system \ isn't \ working|part \ A \ works) = 0.2 \times 0.1 \neq 0.8 \times 0.2 \times 0.1$